# jQuery AJAX JSON parseerror

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I've got a webpage with an AJAX request using jQuery and dataType=json

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: 'api/',
 data: post,
 success: function(data) {}
 dataType: 'json',
 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  var message = myprint(errorThrown)+myprint(textStatus)+myprint(jqXHR);
  // myprint is a custom print function
  alert(message);
 }
}
```

About 1% of the time, I got this alert :

```
{}
"parsererror"
{
 "readyState": 4,
 "responseText": "{\"results\":[\"TEST1\",\"TEST2\"],\"time\":\"0,123\"}",
 "status": 200,
 "statusText": "OK"
}
```

Clearly there is no parseerror. Do you have any idea that I might check ?
Thank you.

Comment: you perhaps do not get json from php/the server.

Comment: @DOCASAREL The response is shown in the `responseText:` line. It sure looks like valid JSON.

Comment: Is it the exact same action which returns both a correct JSON response, and the error (at different times)? Or is there maybe some other function that is called server-side which may be causing the response to be parsed as a string and not as JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Error: "showing-json parse error" that mean: `data format response from server incorrect`.

In client, you set dataType is 'json' but into data response is not json data or may be xml (i not sure, you should check again).

Comment: He's printing the response from the server, since it's included in the `jqXHR` object.

Comment: Where do you see a `<` in the response text?